# gulp: remove a directory from the output destination path

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Please help me with Gulp config

I have two src `scss` folders:

```
styles1/
styles2/
```

In each folder I have next structure for various site pages:

```
styles1/front_page/front.page.scss - root file for front page
styles1/front_page/sections/ - front page sections that are impoted in root file(front.page.scss)
```

My gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('sass-dev', function(done) {
    return gulp.src(['src/scss/**/*.page.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'expanded'}).on('error',sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./frontend/css/temp/'))
});
```

In this way i get output file with next path:

```
./frontend/css/temp/styles1/front_page/front.page.css
```

But I need

```
./frontend/css/temp/styles1/front.page.css
```

More examples of expected result:

```
./frontend/css/temp/styles1/about.page.css
./frontend/css/temp/styles1/contact.page.css
./frontend/css/temp/styles2/front.page.css
./frontend/css/temp/styles2/profile.page.css
```

Is it possible to configure output like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Here are three:

```
gulp.task('sass-dev', function (done) {

  return gulp.src(['src/scss/**/*.page.scss'], {base: 'src/scss/styles1/front_page' }) 

    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./frontend/css/temp/styles1'))  // use with base option, works

});
```

Using the `base` option - this basically sets what you **don't want** in the final destination, which is why `gulp.dest` adds the `styles1` back in.  So you eliminate `"src/scss/styles1/front_page` and send to `'./frontend/css/temp/styles1'.

---

I think a better way os to use the [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) plugin.  It allows you to strip off or flatten directories as you choose.  In your case:

```
const flatten = require("gulp-flatten");


gulp.task('sass-dev', function (done) {

  return gulp.src(['src/scss/**/*.page.scss'])

    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError)

    .pipe(flatten({ subPath: [0, -1] }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./frontend/css/temp'))

 });
```

`flatten({ subPath[0, -1] })` will strip off the last folder, i.e., 'front_page'.

---

```
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const path = require("path");

gulp.task('sass-dev', function (done) {

  return gulp.src(['src/scss/**/*.page.scss'])

    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError))

    .pipe(rename(function (file) {
      let temp = path.dirname(file.dirname);
      file.dirname = temp;
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./frontend/css/temp'))

});
```